# Gravity form After Submission Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have been trying to perform some actions after gravity form submission. I have tried the gform_after_submission hook. But this hook is not working properly for me. I have just added two logs and trying to see if it prints after form submission but In the logs I saw that the after submission hook got triggered but the logs are not getting print.
Can someone please Help me out here:

[image: Funtion written in functions.php]

[image: This is the log file]

Pardon me if the pictures are blur. But please help me out from here.

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures of code and error messages, SO does a great job of formatting both. Does your hook live in functions.php?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes My hook is live in functions.php & Sorry for posting picture rather than the code. I have done as their official document says but even logs lines are not printing.

Comment: Is 'input_7' supposed to be a field id from a specific form?  if so, have you tried adding the form id to the end of the 'gform_after submission' (i.e if your form id is 2 then trying 'gform_after_submission_2')?

Comment: @Rochelle Yes, I have tried to add the Id as well at the end of the hook but it was not working. If we do not add form id in the end of the hook then it will run for all the forms on the site bydefault. I am not able to make it work properly even if I add the form id with it or not.